# How to DRY three controllers using _almost_ the same UIActionSheet delegate code

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I'm an objective-C newbie. I have three controllers that have an `UIActionSheet` delegate with a switch case. The implementation of the delegate is almost the same on the three controllers, but one, where it has one extra case. The code looks bloated since it's almost the same. How could I isolate the delegate and make the code on the three controllers DRY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Inheritance concept. Have one parent controller for all the 3 view controllers. Implement the ActionSheet delegate in the parent controller. Put in the common code in the parent controller. In the one case where you have extra code, override the delegate method.

Comment: Hi Shanti, the thing is that if I do this, then in the controller where I will have to implement the override for the UIActionSheet will have duplicated code plus the couple lines that make it different. So two controllers will have *almost* the same code again.